# Using Three.js ShaderMaterial and writing fragment shaders

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, glsl, shader

I have a few questions about using the Three.js ShaderMaterial.

1. How can I set the color? Three.js seems to provide a lot of the variables through uniforms and ShaderChunk's.I have been unable to determine how to get the color. I assumed it would not be far different from setting the color of any other material. I attempted to copy what was in the DashedLineMaterial but it always came out gray.
2. How can I set a uniform array that I can access in a for loop? This may not be Three.js specific. See the problem below. I describe it above the fragment shader.

I'm trying to  create a material that can handle a special dashed pattern store in an array. negatives are gaps, positives are dashes. eg `[ 0.5, -0.250, 0.250, -0.250 ]`

```
dashedLineShader.uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [

    THREE.UniformsLib[ 'common' ],
    THREE.UniformsLib[ 'fog' ],
    {
        'pattern': { type: 'fv1', value: pattern },  // pattern eg [1.0, -0.5]
        'patternSize': { type: 'i', value: pattern.length },
        'patternLength': { type: 'f', value: totalLength }
    }
] );
```

The vertex shader seems good

```
dashedLineShader.vertexShader = [
    'attribute float lineDistance;',

    'varying float vLineDistance;',

    THREE.ShaderChunk[ 'color_pars_vertex' ],

'void main() {',

    THREE.ShaderChunk[ 'color_vertex' ],
        'vLineDistance = lineDistance;',
        'gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );',
    '}'
].join('\n');
```

When pattern[i] is negative, I want a gap. When pattern[i] is positive, I want a dash. (Eventually 0 will be a dot, but first things first).

This shader doesn't set the color according to the input yet. I tried using ShaderChunks and code copied from the 'dashed' shader included with Three.js, but it always turns out light gray. Below is the shader with some test code. The output is always a solid blue line, so pattern[i] is always 0 and I'm not sure why.

```
dashedLineShader.fragmentShader = [
    'uniform vec3 diffuse;',
    'uniform float opacity;',

    'uniform float pattern[' + pattern.length + '];',
    'uniform float patternLength;',
    'varying float vLineDistance;',

    'void main() {',
    'float pos = mod( vLineDistance, patternLength );',

    'for ( int i = 0; i < ' + pattern.length + '; i++ ) {',
        'pos = pos - abs( pattern[i] );',
        'if ( pos <= 0.0 ) {',
            'if ( pattern[i] < 0.0 ) {',
                'gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, opacity );',
            '} else if (pattern[i] > 0.0 ) {',
                'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, opacity );',
            '} else {',
                'gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, opacity );',
            '}',
            'break;',
        '}',
    '}',
'}'
].join('\n');
```

The confusing part. How do I enter the color?

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    //vertexColors: THREE.NoColors,
    //color: color,
    //attributes: { color: { type: 'c', value: new THREE.Color(color) } },
    uniforms: lineType.uniforms,
    vertexShader: lineType.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: lineType.fragmentShader
});
```

Last notes: this is my first attempt at shaders. The Three.js ShaderMaterial is not completely documented. Been learning by debugging the code, but shaders are difficult to debug.

Comment: The uniforms variable `diffuse` is the color.

Comment: How do I set the color for a particular entity using my ShaderMaterial? ```color: 0x1c30da```? If I use ```gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse, opacity);``` it always comes out as light gray. (.93, .93, .93, 1) I think.

Comment: Here. This fiddle should get you started on the right path: http://jsfiddle.net/3p8vN/.

Comment: Thanks. I was nearly there. Something that threw me off track was the fact that canvas renderer doesn't need ```computeLineDistances()``` to be called. Also, the attribute for lineDistances is handled automatically, you don't have to pass it in to ```ShaderMaterial({...})```. Because of that, I assumed it was called automatically somewhere. Just recently figured out vLineDistance was coming out 0.

This should be enough to get me the rest of the way there. Thanks!

Comment: Good point. I'll be curious as to how you choose to pass the data into the shader.

Comment: I ended up creating a shader for each linetype (generated dynamically). I spent so much time just trying to get GLSL to accept the structure of my for-loop (apparently control flow is limited in if-statements and for-loops) that I don't have time to experiment much more with it for now. Here is what I came up with. http://jsfiddle.net/VyP29/1/

I would love feedback. I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do things.

Comment: Your fiddle renders black for me.

Comment: Interesting... I'm not sure how to validate it for multiple graphics chips. It works fine for me.